# Is there a way to get if a recipe for a target failed or succeded into a variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu

I wanted to get if a recipe for a target failed or succeded into a variable. Is there a way I can do it? My final purpose is to be able to print a modified(or aditional) message instead of the message error that is shown if the recipe fails :

```
path: reciped for target X failed
make: *** [path] Error 1
```

Comment: Is the recipe something simple, like calling a compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

GNU Make communicates with external environment only by files, so what you could do is write the message to file as part of the recipe.